# Architecture question for app which serves data from SQLite in memory

Tags: python, html, ajax, dynamic, server

I am building a dynamic `<div>` into my (very low-traffic) website, which I want to display only *some* data from a memory-based SQLite database running within a Python program on the server. Being a novice in web tech, I can't decide which technologies and principles should go into this project.

Right now, the only decided-upon technologies are Python and Apache. Python, at the very least, needs to be constantly running to fetch data from the external source, format it, and enter it into the database. Problem #1 is where this database should reside. Ideally, I would like it in RAM, since the database will update both often and around the clock. Then the question becomes, "How does one retrieve the data?". Note: the query will never change; I want the web page to receive the same JSON structure only with up-to-date values. From here, I see two options with the first, again, being ideal:

1) Perform some simple "hey someone wants the stuff" interaction with the Python program (remember that this program will be running) whenever someone loads the page, which is responded to with the JSON data. This should be fairly easy with WebSockets, but I understand they have fallen out of favor.

2) Have the Python program periodically create/update an HTML file, which the page loads with jQuery. I could do this with my current knowledge, but I find it inelegant and it would be accepting several compromises such as increased disk read/writes and possibly out-of-date data unless read/writes are increased even further, essentially rendering the benefits from a memory database useless.

So, is my ideal case feasible? Can I implement an API into my Python program to listen for requests? Would the request be made with jQuery? Node.js? PHP? Maybe even with Apache? Do I bypass Python by manipulating the VFS? The techs available feel overwhelming and most online resources only detail generating HTML with Python (Django, Flask, etc.).

Thank you!

Comment: But isn't your problem *exactly* "generating HTML with Python"? Django or Flask seem perfect for what you want to do.

Comment: @DanielRoseman indirectly, I suppose so, but my idea involves JSON as a middleman. Python sends JSON which is rendered into the element on the page by JS

Comment: although, it could directly create the HTML, but the running program would still need a signal to update the HTML upon request.

Answer (score 0):

WSGI is the tech I was looking for!